# PHP in javascript in PHP

Tags: javascript, php

I want to call a javascript function from my PHP code. I have achieved this by using:

```
echo '<script type="text/javascript"> drawChart($id); </script>';
```

This works fine, but I want to get data from my PHP code, which I did using the following:

```
var t_array = ?php echo json_encode($t_array); ?>;
```

(Yes, I know there's a > missing.) I think the PHP closing tag is interfering with the rest of the code. So now my question:
How can I get PHP data without using the PHP tags?

Thanks in advance

Comment: *Yes, I know there's a > missing* So why don't you fix that first?

Comment: AJAX is what I'm thinking of, but I think there are more efficient way.

Comment: where did u declared `$t_array`?

Comment: `drawChart($id);` will be exactly that, because that string is in single-quotes - so it won't be passed as a variable. And there's a `<` missing in front of what should be `<?php`. And that's exactly how you get it, there's no need for AJAX unless you need it dynamically without reloading the website of the PHP values changes.

Comment: Just `var t_array = JSON.parse(<?php echo json_encode($t_array);?>)` should work fine. Use ParseJson function.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3446216/what-is-the-difference-between-single-quoted-and-double-quoted-strings-in-php < this answer seems to be getting some heavy quotage today...

Comment: >Yes, I know there's a > missing So why don't you fix that first?
Because it won't show up here

>Just var t_array = JSON.parse(<?php echo json_encode($t_array);?>) should work fine. Use ParseJson function
I'll try this. Will get back if it worked!

Answer (score 1):

This should work

```
var t_array = <?php echo json_encode($t_array);?>;
```

Comment: Anyway the result of json_encode is a string in php. So I always use Json Parse. Why not suggesting a good practice :)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, none of the given answers worked. What I did was adding arguments to the javascript function and declare the value in the echo. That way, I could just the PHP variables directly. Make sure you use json_encode first!

Answer (score 0):

You just need to concatenate your string properly:

```
// Use double quotation marks so variables can be evaluated in the string
echo "<script type='text/javascript'>" . 
         "var t_array = JSON.parse(" . json_encode($t_array) . ");" .
         "drawChart($id);" . 
     "</script>";
```

Answer (score 0):

Test this:

```
echo "<script type='text/javascript'> drawChart(" . $id . "); </script>";
```

**It's work!**